# Memoization Usage/Cache Storing

Tags: python, caching, memoization

I am writing a program that calculates the Pascal Identity of two variables, hard coded into the program, as I am new into Python and trying out caching and memoization. Here is what I have so far:

```
counter = 0

call_cacheK = {}
   def callTest(n, k):
   global counter

   if n in call_cacheK:
       return call_cacheK[n]  
   if k == 0:
       return 1
   elif k == n:
       return 1 
   elif (1 <= k) and (k <= (n-1)):
       counter += 1
       #call_cacheK[n] = result
       result = ((callTest(n-1, k) + callTest(n-1, k-1)))
   print(result)
   return result

callTest(20, 11)
#167,960
```

My function will output the final real answer with what it has now, but with a lot of outputted answers. I cannot seem to get how to properly store the values to be used in the cache.

How do I properly use `call_cacheK` to store the `result` values I have already used?

Thank you.

Comment: The canonical method for memoization is with a decorator, I suggest you look into that. As for this, you don't seem to be *trying* to put anything into the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see. First, you have a function of two variables, but store result in cache only by one parameter. So `callTest(20, 11)`, `callTest(20, 10)`, `callTest(20, 9)` will have one result in your cache. Lets rewrite your function a little:

```
call_cacheK = {}

def callTest(n, k):
    if (n, k) in call_cacheK:
        return call_cacheK[(n, k)]  
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    elif k == n:
        return 1 
    elif (1 <= k) and (k <= (n-1)):
        result = ((callTest(n-1, k) + callTest(n-1, k-1)))
        call_cacheK[(n, k)] = result
    print(result)
    return result
```

Yes there is no counter variable because I didn't realize why do you need it :)

Also, as far as I can judge by the use of `print(result)`, you probably use the Python3.x. If so, you can use [standard cache implementing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def callTest2(n, k):  
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    elif k == n:
        return 1 
    elif (1 <= k) and (k <= (n-1)):
        result = ((callTest2(n-1, k) + callTest2(n-1, k-1)))
    print(result)
    return result
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you. After you pointed out the single variable issue it become clear my mistake. This was a great solution to the problem.

Comment: @user3194722 You're welcome :) You can also mark an answer as correct if it was helpful for you.